# Partition in a tree shaped distributed network

Tags: graphs, trees, distributed-systems, partitions, synchronization

We are given a synchronic undirected tree shaped network, with $n$ indexed nodes.

We know that there is at least one node with at least $\log_k n$ neighbors, $k>1000$, and $k$ is given.

We need to divide the network into $\log_2 n$ distinct groups, with at least one link between any two groups, and each node has no more than $10$ neighbors in its group.

Any thoughts? I tried to choose the nodes with at least $\log_k n$ neighbors first but it doesn't work.

I’m using the LOCAL distributed computational model.

Comment: what computation model are you using? proof-labeling schemes? CONGEST?

Comment: Or maybe a totally different computation model? It would be nice if you link \ explain to the exact computation model you are using